# Soviet space exploration board game (now with pictures)

Tags: identify-this-game

I have an archaeological question :). I used to have this space exploration board game that my father bought in the USSR in the 80s. I can't remember its name and I've been trying to find it on Russian websites for several days now, but it seems to be rather obscure and rare. I remember it had a board put together from several separate cardboard pieces (not foldable as usual). There were pictures of various Soviet space probes and satellites printed around the board. The main theme, if I recall correctly, was to put your satellites around major planets. The dominant color on the board was dark blue, with pictures of planets and stars. I have already checked that it was NOT any of the following:

- Большое космическое путешествие (Great cosmic voyage)
- Риск (Risk)
- Космос (Cosmos)
- В космос (Into the cosmos)
- Приключения на Луне (Adventures on the Moon)

Any help in identifying this game will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I remember one more thing, although not that relevant. The player's pieces look a bit like [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSpielstein_.jpg), although slightly more slender and reminiscent of a space rocket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, after a visit to my grandmother I was able to unearth the box with the game. To my delight it was almost completely intact. It's called *"Путешествие в космос"* (*"A trip to space"*). It's really hard to find anything related to this game on Google - all the results refer to a newer game by the same title. I'll post some more details, including a scan of the manual and photos of the board, later today or maybe tomorrow.

EDIT:

Ok, while waiting for the BoardGameGeek submission to be accepted, I decided to post the photos now for everyone to see. Enjoy!!!

If someone would be interested in the English translation of the manual, let me know.

EDIT 2:

The submission to BoardGameGeek has finally been accepted. You can view it [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/156985/puteshestvie-v-kosmos). Have fun!!!

#### Box

[image: Box]

#### Manual Cover

[image: Manual cover]

#### Manual Text

[image: Manual Text]

#### Board Front (Upper Left)

[image: Board Front (Upper Left)]

#### Board Front (Upper Right)

[image: Board Front (Upper Right)]

#### Board Front (Lower Right)

[image: Board Front (Lower Right)]

#### Board Front (Lower Left)

[image: Board Front (Lower Left)]

#### Board Back (Lower Left)

[image: Board Back (Lower Left)]

#### Board Back (Lower Right)

[image: Board Back (Lower Right)]

#### Board Back (Upper Right)

[image: Board Back (Upper Right)]

#### Board Back (Upper Left)

[image: Board Back (Upper Left)]

Comment: You should submit it to boardgamegeek as well - the more games in the DB there, the better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CharlesBoyung, I definitely will :)

Comment: @WojciechGac, once you've submitted it to boardgamegeek, post a link to it here for all us curious people.

Comment: Ok, I submitted the game and am now waiting for the submission to be moderated.

Comment: Do you know how long it usually takes for a submission to be verified? It's still in the submission queue and I don't know what to expect.

Comment: Any update on the BGG submission?
It took a couple of days for my game to be approved, and it's a modern/English game!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, so far nothing new on the submission.